# QGIS python processing tools - saving/exporting graph

Tags: python, gis, qgis

I just tried QGIS processing tools for the first time.

When using shortest path search for the first time, the algorithm is building a path graph (of course). However, the graph is never re-used. Every time the algorithm is used, the graph building starts again. I am not familiar with the exact code used for it, but I guess the graph is network-wide, not related to the specific points I selected. So is there a way to re-use the graph? Er even export it to a file?

My network is large (more than 200k features), so efficiency is important. The network is rarely updated, so calculating a graph could easily be done just once in a while.

I looked up the docs and settings of processing tools, and this option seems to be unavailable (which is surprising). So maybe I am missing something, or maybe someone could suggest a way to serialize the graph and save it using python code? I am using QGIS 3.1 (A Coruna).

As found on [anitagraser github page](https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-Processing-tools/blob/master/2.2/scripts/point_layer_to_route.py) processing tools that use graphs look straightforward using Dijkstra algoritghm.

```py
builder = QgsGraphBuilder( crs )
graph = builder.graph()

from_id = graph.findVertex(from_point)
to_id = graph.findVertex(to_point)

(tree,cost) = QgsGraphAnalyzer.dijkstra(graph,from_id,0)
```

I guess using that would require building a different tool and not using the user-friendly shortest path search tool with a nice GUI and integration with point selecting and so on. That would be not acceptable. The goal was to be able to perform the same task on any pc with un-altered QGIS (no add-ins needed, only a script). But it may be that it is not possible. So the problem leads to:

- is it possible to *tweak* the existing processing tool, to cache the graph or even store it in a file?
- can I somehow duplicate the tool and apply some small changes?

I asked this question already on [gis stack echange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/354097/159907). My question probably has a programming answer, so I am reposting [as an exception](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75012).
[image]